# Reducing the height of a div by a set amount?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that can dynamically grow; but due to some of the elements being higher than what they are by having a position: relative; the div is a little taller than what it needs to be.

The elements can have multiple lines; so the height of the div is not-constant, but regardless of how many lines these elements are, there's always a little "overhang"/ blank space.

Is there any way I can reduce the height of a div by a fixed amount. I'm thinking along the lines of

100% of the div's height - 20px

Answer (score 4):

Probably could with [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
height: calc(100% - 20px);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
div {
   height: calc(100% - 20px)
}
```