# Reduce div height by a set amount

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a website and I have a problem. I have a 'card' div that has an image inside it that i moved halfway outside of it using `position:relative`. My problem is that, when I write text inside said div, there is always a bit of white space at the bottom, exactly the size of the half the image (17vw).

I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246649/reducing-the-height-of-a-div-by-a-set-amount), and I used it like this: `calc(100% - 17vw)` but it isn´t working.

You can see the example of the problem in my website http://nuno99costa.xyz/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin-top: -17vw` instead of `top: -17vw` on line 54 of style.css

(You can also remove the `position: relative` as well.)

A negative `margin-top` removes space above, whereas `top` just moves the element.

Comment: css `translate` is another handy feature to use

Comment: @admcfajn You could use that, but it still got the whitespace issue :)

Comment: @ChrisHappy yeah, that wouldn't specifically apply to this one, but comes in handy in this variety of problems. A tertiary to your primary.